# Python Stop Processes in Generator

Tags: python

I have an "AbstractCollector" class that provides a record generator from a `collect()` method. I also have a "MultiCollector" which can run multiple "AbstractCollector"s in other processes, and return their combined results from a single generator (using `Queue`).

My MultiCollector class looks like this-

```
class MultiCollector(AbstractDataCollector):
    # ... 

    def collect(self):
        sub_collectors: List[AbstractDataCollector] = # ... create sub collectors
        

        m = multiprocessing.Manager()
        q = m.Queue()

        futures = []
        with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=self.config.parallel_scans) as executor:
            for sub_collector in sub_collectors:
                f = executor.submit(self.run_collector_process, q, sub_collector)
                futures.append(f)

            while receiving:
                try:
                    message = q.get_nowait()
                except Empty:
                    time.sleep(0.01)
                    message = None

                if message:
                    yield message

                # Check for any future still running
                receiving = False
                for future in futures:
                    if not future.done():
                        receiving = True
                        break

            for future in futures:
                # Force complete
                future.result(0)

    @staticmethod
    def run_collector_process(queue: Queue, collector: AbstractDataCollector):
        for data in collector.collect():
            queue.put(data)
```

What this looks like is:

```
my_multi_collector = MultiCollector()

for record in my_multi_collector.collect():
  print(record)
```

But I would like to stop the collection process early after an arbitrary number of returned records. So under normal circumstances I could do something link this:

```
my_multi_collector = MultiCollector()

i = 0
for record in my_multi_collector.collect():
  i += 1
  if i > 20:
    break
  
  print(record)
```

But with my multicollector, when I break here the processes spawned by `collect()` do not know to stop.

Is it possible to know when a generator is broken out of so I can stop the spawn processes within `collect()`?

Comment: Not 100% (thus not an answer), but I believe changing to `records = my_multi_collector.collect()`, then `for record in records:`, then adding an explicit `records.close()` when you decide you're done should raise `GeneratorExit` in the generator, which should trigger the `with` cleanup for the executor, and if that's not enough, allow you to do whatever other explicit cleanup is needed by catching `GeneratorExit` and performing that work manually.

Comment: This is the answer! In fact you don't even need to call `close()` on the generator, breaking out the generator also throws a `GeneratorExit` exception. All you have to do is wrap the `yield` in a try-catch.

Comment: Yeah, the `GeneratorExit` will be thrown when the generator is cleaned up by any means, the explict `.close()` just gets guaranteed timing (where a reference cycle or a non-reference-counted interpreter might take cause an arbitrarily long delay between breaking out and the generator actually getting cleaned). Using `contextlib.closing` might make it slightly nicer, `with closing(my_multi_collector.collect()) as records:`, `for record in records:`, and you don't explicitly call `.close()` (and it's always called even if you exit via an exception).

Answer (score 0):

When a generator is garbage-collected or explicitly closed (via the `.close()` method), a `GeneratorExit` exception is raised within the generator. You can catch this exception to perform manual cleanup if `with` statements and the like aren't covering your use case. And you can ensure `close` is called explicitly to avoid arbitrary cleanup delays when reference cycles are present (or you're on a non-CPython interpreter that uses a strategy other than reference counting for memory management).

So in your caller, you can change:

```
for record in my_multi_collector.collect():
    ... body goes here ...
```

to:

```
# At top of file
from contextlib import closing  # Allows easy guarantee close behavior

# Replacing existing code
with closing(my_multi_collector.collect()) as results:
    for record in records:
        ... body goes here ...

# When code dedents out of with, generator closed automatically, including on exception
```

Then if your `with` statements within the generator aren't enough, you can explicitly wrap code with:

```
try:
    ... code goes here ...
except GeneratorExit:
    ... cleanup on early exit goes here ...
    raise  # Let exception continue bubbling to ensure cleanup finishes
finally:
    ... cleanup that must always run even when run to completion goes here ...
```

to perform any manual cleanup required (omitting `except GeneratorExit:` or `finally:` depending on what sort of cleanup conditions apply).